# Undefined __set_state() magic method in PHP 7.1

Tags: php, php-7.1

I have a issue with calling the `__set_state` method on a class

**The PHP version is 7.1**

By calling `Fab\Vidi\Grid\CheckBoxRenderer::__set_state()` gives me an `Exception` which says: "Call to `undefined` `method` `Fab\Vidi\Grid\CheckBoxRenderer::__set_state()`"

Comment: Could you post you code that cause problem please?

Comment: It's not mandatory to implement the `__set_state` method.  Are you sure the class you're calling it on implements it?